# Aws S3 AccessDenied: when uploading object

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a s3 bucket called `MyBucket`.

The permission like below:
[image]

The Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/files/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Inside the bucket, I have a folder called `files`. Inside `files`, the object can be viewed by the public

For the IAM user, I have attached an inline policy below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/files/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I upload the object to the bucket using nodejs:

```
s3.upload({
            ACL: 'public-read',
            Bucket: this.app.settings.aws.s3.bucket,
            Body: bufferFromFile,
            Key: `files/${result.id}/${data.fileName}`,
        }, {}).promise();
```

I got `AccessDenied: Access Denied` error.

How to solve it?

**Update 1:**

I try to add `s3:PutObject` in bucket policy suggested by the comment, but the error still the same.
I am using EC2 to host the nodejs code

**Update 2**

I try to upload an object to the bucket using below CLI and it works.

```
aws s3 cp s3Test.html s3://MyBucket/files/
```

**Update 3**

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket MyBucket --key files/s3Test.html --body s3Test.html --acl public-read

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

**Update 4**

just realize there is another Managed policy in same IAM user which might be related.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:CreateJob",
                "s3:HeadBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:*:*:accesspoint/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:*:*:job/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Not sure whether this policy will affect the issue.

Comment: Your `s3.upload` actually uses credentials of the IAM user with that policy?

Comment: @Marcin that's true

Comment: Is the bucket encrypted?

Comment: @Marcin what do you mean `encrypted`?

Comment: I guess not then, if you did not explicitly set it up.

Comment: The issue is limited to node-js? Did you try uploading using aws cli to confirm?

Comment: @Marcin I don't think so. It was ok before

Comment: The error is saying that the credentials being used by your Node code does not have permission to `PutObject` to that bucket. Therefore, something is not as it seems. Can you _temporarily_ change the bucket policy to include `PutObject` for _everybody_ (just like `GetObject`)? That will help narrow-down whether the problem is related to the policies, or in the code. Where is the code running -- on an EC2 instance, or your own computer?

Comment: @John Rotenstein please see my update above

Comment: So you are using IAM instance role, or IAM user to run your code? Its confusing.

Comment: @Marcin I am using IAM user credential(access key/secret key etc)

Comment: I agree with @Marcin --- if your code is running on an Amazon EC2 instance, it typically obtains permission from an IAM Role assigned to the instance. Or, you can store credentials via the AWS CLI `aws configure` command. However, the fact that it failed after adding `PutObject` in the public Bucket Policy says that either there is another permission required, or the code is not accessing the correct bucket and path. You can view the CloudTrail logs to see what API calls have been received by AWS, which can help identify which permissions might be required.

Comment: @John Rotenstein I just create cloudtrail for my bucket. but when I open the json log file, there is no `putObject` found

Comment: @John Rotenstein please see my update 3

Comment: @Marcin please see my update 3

Comment: `myBucket` is actually the name you use, or just a placeholder? The policy says it is `MyBucket`? You could be trying to access other account bucket.

Comment: @Marcin it's just a fake bucket name. Please also check my `update 4`

Comment: Why do you use `--acl public-read`? Don't you block that? Does it work without it?

Comment: Seriously... use CloudTrail to find the actual request that was denied. It might take a while for the log to come through, but it will provide valuable information. You might even try running `aws iam get-user` to confirm who IAM thinks you are, and you could call similar code from Node for comparison. FYI, `--body s3Test.html` will just pass `s3Test.html`, not the file but that is fine for testing purposes (normally use `--body file://s3Test.html`). Using `--acl public-read` makes every uploaded object public, which you probably don't want to do since you have a Bucket Policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after removing `ACL: 'public-read'` from the code.

@Marcin and @John Rotenstein have provided good insight and direction for finding the reasons in the comment. Really appreciate it!

```
s3.upload({
            ACL: 'public-read', //remove this line
            Bucket: this.app.settings.aws.s3.bucket,
            Body: bufferFromFile,
            Key: `files/${result.id}/${data.fileName}`,
        }, {}).promise();
```